# open layers6: reproject epsg 28992 to epsg 4326

Tags: html-lists, map-projections, openlayers-6, epsg

I want to reproject my local-geoJson file in epsg:28992 to the OSM EPSG:4326 in OpenLayers.
I have the feeling I am close to the solution but I don't know what the next step is. I've tried and looked for multiple examples here at SO but I've  the feeling I'm missing a certain line of code somewhere.

For now the code below shows me my local gjson file at null-island.
How do I tell  Open Layer to reproject it to the Netherlands?

thanks in advance.

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.6.0/proj4.js"></script>
  <script src="http://epsg.io/28992.js"></script>

  <!-- Include OpenLayers -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.1.1/build/ol.js"></script>

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.1.1/css/ol.css"
    />

    <style>
        html, body, #map {
        margin: 0;
        height: 75%;
        width: 75%;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        background-color: #04041b;
      }
    </style>

    <title>A simple web app</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script>
      // create an empty OpenLayers map
      var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
          center: [0, 0],
          zoom: 2
        })
      });

      // create OpenStreetMap base layer
      var baseMap = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.XYZ({
          url: 'http://{a-c}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
          attributions: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        })
      });

      map.addLayer(baseMap);


/*
//reproject

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON({
            defaultDataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
            featureProjection: 'EPSG:28992'
        })).readFeatures(geojsonObject)
      });
//reproject
*/

    //LocalJson
var geojsonSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(

    ),
    projection: 'EPSG:28992',
  url: 'PS2019_buurt.geo.json'
});


var geojsonStyle = new ol.style.Style({
  fill: new ol.style.Fill({
    color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6)' // red
  }),
  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
    color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)' // black
  })
});

var geojsonLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: geojsonSource,
  style: geojsonStyle
});
      map.addLayer(geojsonLayer);
//LocalJson   

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your features should alwways be transformed to the view projection:

```
    var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON({
            dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
            featureProjection: map.getView().getProjection(),
        })).readFeatures(geojsonObject)
      });
```

(the `defaultDataProjection` option was renamed to `dataProjection` since OpenLayers 5)

Currently your view is using the default web mercator as used by OSM.

If you want to view everything (features and OSM) in EPSG:28992 you would need to register proj4 and set the view projection

```
      ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);

      var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
          center: [0, 0],
          zoom: 2,
          projection: 'EPSG:28992'
        })
      });
```

If using `geojsonSource` with a `url` you do not need to specify projection, the data is automatically transformed to the view projection.

If however if the data in your geojson is in EPSG:28992 you would need

```
    ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);

    var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON({
            dataProjection: 'EPSG:28992',
            featureProjection: map.getView().getProjection(),
        })).readFeatures(geojsonObject)
      });
```

or

```
     ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);

     var geojsonSource = new ol.source.Vector({
       format: new ol.format.GeoJSON({
         dataProjection: 'EPSG:28992'
       }),
       url: 'PS2019_buurt.geo.json'
     });
```

Comment: thank you for the clarification. I understand I have reprojected the project to EPSG:28992 instead of only the GeoJson file to EPSG:4326? No problem anyway. It works :) 

But is it OK that I see a black circle at the north-pole?

Comment: OSM has no coverage north of 85 degrees so if you reproject it to a projection which includes the pole you will see a hole